# Can I use generics on a single method to both check instance and cast the object

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible in Java 8 to write a single method with generics, which both checks an Object is of the correct class, then returns that object cast correctly. Something like:

```
private T check(final Object value) {
    assertThat(value, instanceOf(T.class));
    return (T) value;
}
```

so that it can be called like this:

```
String strValue = check<String>(objValue);
```

Comment: What you're asking for is exactly equivalent to a normal cast.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Almost. A normal cast would throw a `ClassCastException` if it failed.

Comment: Well, yes, and presumably assertThat would throw some assertion exception or error that would probably be strictly less useful.

Comment: At runtime `T` will be `Object` due to type erasure. Joe C's answer is the only way to know the actual type of `T` at runtime. But I agree with Louis that an AssertionError or something similar would be less useful than a ClassCastException.

Comment: For clarity, I am aware of the normal casting conventions, however, the code in question is for a generic interface to a database. The name and type of the property are retrieved first, then the object is checked to see if it is of the correct type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to achieve this is by passing the `Class` object that you want to check against.

```
private <T> T check(final Object value, Class<T> clazz) {
    assertThat(clazz.isInstance(value));
    return clazz.cast(value); //Throws ClassCastException if not valid
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was pretty close, but could not quite get a version that had no warnings.